# Stuck In a command block induced death loop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a new world called "Fun With Redstone".

I had a "genius" idea to make a zombie killing mini-game, so I put in the super fast redstone clock `/kill @e[Type=Zombie]` and shortly after, realized my blunder.

My world is now stuck in a death loop where every time I respawn I just get killed again.

Can anyone help me to get out of that loop? Maybe there are hidden files or something? I don't wanna reset my whole world, since there are other projects there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use MCEdit, you can still use NBT Explorer. [Download it here.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665)
Now, open it up and select your world.

[image: Select your world]

Then, you want to click on Search->Find. Tick the `value` box and enter your command or just a part of it.

[image: Search for your command]

After a short amount of time, NBTExplorer will have found the problem causing command block.

[image: The command that causes trouble.]

So now you can easily edit the command by double clicking on it. Make sure to click on the save button at the top, to ensure your changes got saved and you're done.

Comment: Nice. This is even cleaner than my answer's solution. Have a +1.

Comment: I forgot I asked this... 3 years later and I had the same problem again. I ended up searching for an answer, eventually found this one and it actually worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to delete the command block or to break the redstone. Alternatively if you are fast enough you may be able to run a command before you die.

Comment: It does require an mod... And I had trouble with that mod at first so maybe it isn't all that good of an idea.

Comment: McEdit is not a mod, it is an external program

Comment: Oh. It's still a bit hard to use and to download. It's not easy at all. So an easier way might help better.

Comment: I agree with @Luiyay. MCEdit is an immensely powerful tool, which can make it quite confusing and complicated for first time users. In this case, it's the equivalent of using a CNC router to drill a simple hole.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this without mods or external editors. A feature of the standalone Minecraft server is that it has a configuration option to disable command blocks. We can exploit this to save your game.

1. Back up your save. (Always prudent.)
2. Get and install the server somewhere on your local machine. ([Follow the directions on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server) if you've never done this before.)
3. Run the server once to make sure it's working, and that you can connect to it. Then stop the server.
4. Delete the contents of the server's `world` folder and replace it with a copy of the contents of your affected save folder.
5. Edit the server's `server.properties` file. Change or add the line to say:

   ```
    enable-command-block=false
   ```
6. Run the server and connect. Go find your errant command block and fix it or disable its clock. Wait a minute to make sure an auto-save happens, or just issue the `save-all` command in the server console. Stop the server again.
7. Copy the contents of the server's `world` file into your singleplayer saves directory. (If you want to be super-cautious, copy this into a *new* save folder.)
8. Play singleplayer and confirm that you don't die instantly anymore!

Answer (score 2):

If it is by any chance on a server, go to your server properties folder and disable command blocks. After that, get back on your world and destroy the command block that is keeping you in the loop. Once finished, close your server and turn command blocks back on. Once you finished, it should be back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an little trick for ya:

Copy this:

```
/Gamemode 3
```

Go to your world and quickly press `Ctrl + V` and Enter. Now, when you are right above the command block, copy this:

```
/Gamemode 0
```

Then go to settings, controls and set the "destroy block" (or something) control from button 1 (left-click) to Enter. Now press `Ctrl + V` and press Enter twice ASAP. Ta-da!

**Having trouble with the three keys?** 
Use an AutoTyper program and press the type key. Now it's reduced to two keys to press in an tick. And yes, pressing three keys in a tick is possible. You might want to use some hacks if you are still having trouble with two keys. (AutoRespawn or something...) Also, if this is multiplayer, simply turn command blocks off in the menu thing.

Comment: Have you actually managed to do this faster than a superfast clock?

Comment: Took me like 19 tries but it's possible.

Comment: For one thing, `gamemode 0` is Survival mode, you want `gamemode 1`. I also believe that `kill @e` kills everything, including spectators.

Answer (score -1):

I got an way to fix it without anything like world edit.

1.Launch the Minecraft launcher and make a new profile

2.Name it

3.Set the profile's version to 1.8.9

4.You wont be able to be killed but go to the spot where the command block is. (You cant see it but I believe it seems like a black spot)

5. Blow it up with TNT

6.Go back to your other profile

7.The command block has the repeat on but it erased the command so delete the command block.

Comment: That will only work if the killing command block is a repeating or chain command block from 1.9. If it's a regular command block, downgrading shouldn't be an issue. It will also delete *everything* that is present in the world that was added in 1.9, such as Elytra.

Comment: I don't think you can use TNT on it anyway... But MrLemon is right as well, it won't cause issues when downgrading, and it will cause backwards compatibility issues when you try going back.