# I can't break a redstone clock that keeps killing me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was trying to make a redstone clock that kills a mob with a certain name in a 200 block radius and I messed up and it just kills me. Is there anyway and can break it without dying?

Comment: Mcedit will be helpful

Comment: This question was already answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/212236/30132).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had that problem when I'm making my map before that teleport to somewhere.

**To fix this:**

- MCEdit. http://www.mcedit.net

Go to MCEdit and fly to the command block where it killed you. And select one of the redstone and press "Delete Blocks". It should works.

- Command and coor.

If you are lazy and you know where is thee command block is (coor). You can use `/setblock x y z minecraft:air` to delete it.

- Spectator mode (Idk if work)

If your version is newer than 1.8. You can do `/gamemode 3` and go to the command block position. Then press F3 and get the coordinate of the redstone.
Then use the command above to remove it.

Also if possible can you let me see the command that killed you?

Killing custom name mob in 200 blocks radius: `/kill @e[name=mobName, r=200]`
(I think that's right)